# The relationship between specific discharge and flux

Tags: hydrology

How are specific discharge and flux linked?

Is flux simply `specific discharge × area`? And when we speak of flux of an element eg. N-flux, is that `specific discharge × concentration × area`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the fluid dynamics description of flux, which is the rate of volume flow across a unit area.

**1.**

> Is flux simply specific discharge × area?

Yes you are correct.

$$Specific~Discharge = \frac{Volumetric~Flux}{Area}$$

therefore

$$Volumetric~Flux = Specific~Discharge~\cdot~Area$$

**2.**

> And when we speak of flux of an element eg. N-flux, is that specific
>   discharge × concentration × area?

When you speak of an element the rationale is the same but will depend on whether the model you are devising contains 1D, 2D or 3D fluid elements. The latter is defined as above.